# How to do two-column lookup to produce summary? (Google sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

I have a simple two column data set:

```
Users  | Action
---------------
User 1 | Payment
User 2 | Payment
User 3 | Payment
User 4 | Confirm
User 2 | Confirm
```

And would like to produce this summary:

```
User   | Payment| Confirm
-------------------------
User 1 | TRUE   | FALSE
User 2 | TRUE   | TRUE
User 3 | TRUE   | FALSE
User 4 | FALSE  | TRUE
```

Here is a sample Sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1869dg2-0bNPFTBs-QtCiFdXC16ih8rAL4g8PihEUwLk/edit?usp=sharing

The data itself will be coming dynamically from the Google Analytics add-in. The `Action`s are given, not dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By manipulating input arrays and passing them to query, We get the requested result:

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A2:A6,--(B2:B6="Payment"),--(B2:B6="Confirm")},"Select Col1,Sum(Col2),sum(Col3) group by Col1  label sum(Col2) 'Payment', sum(Col3) 'Confirm' format sum(Col2) 'TRU\E;;FAL\S\E',sum(Col3) 'TRU\E;;FAL\S\E'"))
```